# Builder GEM XML formatting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xml, rubygems

I'm using the Ruby Gem Builder, and I need this output..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fileAttachment> "name of file here.xls"
  <Data>zip</Data>
  <Size>7434</Size>
</fileAttachment>
```

My code is below, but the file name next to "fileAttachment" just isn't working.. This is something simple I'm just not seeing it?? The error says I can't mix text with a block.. makes sense I just don't know the correct syntax.

```
 xml = Builder::XmlMarkup.new(:indent => 2 )
 xml.instruct! :xml,:version=>"1.0", :encoding => "utf-8"
   xml.fileAttachment("name of file here.xls") do
     xml.Data "zip"
     xml.Size "7434"
   end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to use the `text!` method:

```
xml.fileAttachment do
  xml.text! "name of file here.xls"
  xml.Data "zip"
  xml.Size "7434"
end
```